# Row level atomic MERGE REPLACE in BigQuery

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery, etl, acid

For my use case I'm working with data identifiable by unique key at the source exploded into n (non deterministic) number of target entries loaded into BigQuery tables for analytic purposes.

Building this ETL to use Mongo recent Change Stream feature I would like to drop all entries in BigQuery and then load the new entries atomically.

Exploring BigQuery DML I see a [MERGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) operation is supported, but only `WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE` or `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` is possible.

I'm interested in a *WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE, AND FOLLOW BY AN INSERT* operation.

How would I implement such ETL in BigQuery while remaining atomic or eventually consistent as possible in terms of data availability and correctness.

---

EDIT 1: I would like to provide a concrete example to elaborate.

The lowest granularity of uniqueness I have on this dataset is `user_id`. Rows are not uniquely identifiable.

**Example**

### 1.

Updated user object received from mongo change stream:

```
user={_id: "3", name="max", registered="2018-07-05" q=["a", "b", "c"]}
```

### 2.

Current BigQuery.user_q holds

```
| user_id | q |
...
|    3    | a |
|    3    | b |
...
```

### 3.

Transform code loads modified user object into BigQuery.user_q_incoming

```
| user_id | q |
|    3    | a |
|    3    | b |
|    3    | c |
```

### 4.

MERGE between `user_q` and `user_q_incoming`:

1. 2 rows in `user_q` that belong to `user_id 3` are DELETED
2. 3 rows in `user_q_incoming` that belong to `user_id 3` are INSERTED.
3. Rest of the data (`...`) in `user_q` is left in place, unmodified.

### 5.

BigQuery.user_q holds

```
| user_id | q |
...
|    3    | a |
|    3    | b |
|    3    | c |
...
```

For example user might delete a question from his profile. Leaving the remaining rows to be `q=["a", "c"]`. I need this to translate into the BigQuery world view as well.

Answer (score 3):

INSERT is supported by BigQuery DML

> A MERGE statement is a DML statement that can combine INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations into a single statement and perform the operations atomically.

for example

```
MERGE dataset.Inventory T
USING dataset.NewArrivals S
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND product LIKE '%washer%' THEN
  INSERT (product, quantity) VALUES(product, quantity)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND product LIKE '%washer%' THEN
  DELETE
```

so, you should be good to go with your ETL

> EDIT based on more specific details added to question

Ok, I see  - I think in this case MERGE will not apply as INSERT can be done ONLY for NOT MATCH clause. Someone might figure out how to trick MERGE to work in this case, but meantime below solution does what you want to achieve - i think so :o)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.user_q` (user_id INT64, q STRING) AS
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.user_q`
WHERE NOT user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM `project.dataset.user_q_incoming`)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.user_q_incoming`
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM `project.dataset.user_q`)
```

Comment: Mikhail, please see my edit describing the merge operation I had in mind.

Comment: I see now, this is "little" different from how I read your question initially. See update in my answer - hope it will work for you now :o) Also note, even though formally it does what you asked  - but take into consideration [cost of DML operations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#dml)

Comment: @MaximVeksler - did you have chance to try?

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar question and one walk-around to make MERGE work (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927#comment9).

Basically, something like following should work,

```
MERGE `project.dataset.user_q` T
USING (
  SELECT *, false AS is_insert FROM `project.dataset.user_q_incoming`
UNION ALL
  SELECT *, true AS is_insert FROM `project.dataset.user_q_incoming`
) S
ON T.user_id = S.user_id and NOT is_insert
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND is_insert THEN
  INSERT(user_id, q) VALUES(user_id, q)
```

Ideally, following is what you need, but it's not supported yet.

```
MERGE `project.dataset.user_q`
USING `project.dataset.user_q_incoming`
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT(user_id, q) VALUES(user_id, q)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM `project.dataset.user_q_incoming`) THEN
  DELETE
```

Comment: thank's for this. What is the performance of UNION or the expected performance of it in general? 

Side effect: Currently I'm doing a MERGE DELETE followed by a load https://gist.github.com/maximveksler/c4c708ad792672ada39c5dd2dc3637c3 this is not atomic and is not a good solution but it allows me to do an "INSERT *" rather than having to specify INSERT (fields...). Can I do the same for merge?

Comment: Maxim, I've commented at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927#comment14 suggesting to use CROSS JOIN UNNEST([true, false]) instead of UNION ALL, which gives better performance.

Unfortunately it's not supported for "INSERT *". We are aware of such inconvenience. Will give update once there is a better solution.

Comment: this will not work if you are using partitions and have passed the limit (1000) :(